# Azure Table Storage, some fields are missing in my stored entity

Tags: azure, nosql, decimal, azure-table-storage

I've created an entity to store in azure table storage:
But all the entities that are of decimal type are missing

[image]

If I go an azure explorer I see that some fields are missing

[image]

All the field that are of type decimal are missing, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the data type from `decimal` to `double` and that should solve the problem.

Based on the [`supported data types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#property-types), `decimal` is not supported. `double` data type is supported which maps to `Edm.Double` OData type.